# convert multi level list of dictionaries into data frame or data set

Tags: python, json, pandas

how can i convert a dataframe into some time series data frame ?
|index|Device_id|Attribute_00|Attribute_01|
|---|---|---|---|
|0|0123456|{'channel': 'BATTERY', 'timezone': '2023-01-28 22:02:00', 'Interval': 120, 'Readings': [3.5561, 3.5571, 3.5612, 3.5602, 3.5602, 3.5622, 3.5612, 3.5622, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5653, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5663, 3.5643, 3.5673, 3.5684, 3.5653, 3.5694, 3.5673, 3.5673]},{'channel': 'BATTERY', 'timezone': '2023-01-28 23:00:00', 'Interval': 120, 'Readings': [3.5714, 3.5602, 3.5612, 3.5622, 3.5622, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5663, 3.5684, 3.5663, 3.5663, 3.5673, 3.5673, 3.5684, 3.5673, 3.5694, 3.5663, 3.5694, 3.5694, 3.5694, 3.5673, 3.5694, 3.5704]},{'channel': 'WATER', 'timezone': '2023-01-29 00:00:00', 'Interval': 120, 'Readings': [3.5694, 3.5582, 3.5622, 3.5622, 3.5612, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5653, 3.5653, 3.5653, 3.5673, 3.5653, 3.5673, 3.5673, 3.5663, 3.5704, 3.5684, 3.5694, 3.5694, 3.5684, 3.5704, 3.5684, 3.5694, 3.5694]}|{'channel': 'BATTERY', 'timezone': '2023-01-29 01:00:00', 'Interval': 120, 'Readings': [3.5673, 3.552, 3.5571, 3.5571, 3.5602, 3.5602, 3.5612, 3.5612, 3.5592, 3.5602, 3.5633, 3.5592, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5653, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5673, 3.5653, 3.5663, 3.5653, 3.5684]}|
|1|0123457|||

something like

| device_id | channel | timezone | readings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456 | battery | 2022-04-12 15:00:00 | [3.5561, 3.5571, 3.5612, 3.5602, 3.5602, 3.5622, 3.5612, 3.5622, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5653, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5643, 3.5663, 3.5663, 3.5643, 3.5673, 3.5684, 3.5653, 3.5694, 3.5673, 3.5673] |
| 0123456 | water | 2022-04-12 16:00:00 | [3.5694, 3.5582, 3.5622, 3.5622, 3.5612, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5643, 3.5633, 3.5643, 3.5653, 3.5653, 3.5653, 3.5673, 3.5653, 3.5673, 3.5673, 3.5663, 3.5704, 3.5684, 3.5694, 3.5694, 3.5684, 3.5704, 3.5684, 3.5694, 3.5694] |

or there is any other method or any suggestions ?

```
import json
from pandas import json_normalize
attribute_columns = df.filter(like='attribute').columns
for column in attribute_columns:
    # df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df[column])
    # df[column].apply(pd.Series)
    # df = pd.DataFrame([{'readings': i.get('readings')} for i in df[column]])
```

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructor of your input for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact logic and inputs are not fully clear, but you can likely use something like:

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='attribute'))

out = (
 df.melt(df.columns.difference(cols))
   .explode('value', ignore_index=True).drop(columns=['variable'])
   .pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('value')).set_axis(d.index)))
)
```

*NB. if you have strings as input, use `pd.json_normalize(d.pop('value').apply(ast.literal_eval))`.*

Output:

```
   Device_id  channel             timezone  interval            readings
0     123456  battery  2022-04-12 15:00:00     120.0    [2.5, 2.6, 2.56]
1     123456    water  2022-04-12 16:00:00     120.0        [25, 26, 25]
2     123456    water  2022-04-12 17:00:00     120.0        [25, 20, 10]
3     123457  battery  2022-04-12 13:00:00     120.0  [2.47, 2.56, 2.64]
4     123457    water  2022-04-12 14:00:00     120.0         [20, 2, 10]
5     123457    water  2022-04-12 15:00:00     120.0        [25, 20, 10]
6     123456  battery  2022-04-12 18:00:00     120.0    [2.5, 2.6, 2.56]
7     123457      NaN                  NaN       NaN                 NaN
```